# How are Lightsabers created in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

Can anyone please explain how lightsabers are created in the *Star Wars* universe or is does it occur magically? Also when someone is training to be a Jedi, how and when will he receive or procure his lightsaber? Is it like there is some amount of lightsabers available and these are reused?

Can anyone give explanations to these questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Lightsabers are constructed** by every Jedi knight or a Jedi knight may also choose to use his master's lightsaber if the master is in no longer need of it ( like if he is dead) to show his respect for his master.

> A lightsaber crystal was a term used to describe any variety of
>   crystals, gems, stones, or other objects used as the focus in the
>   construction of a lightsaber.
>
> At the heart of every lightsaber was a set of crystals that resonated
>   to produce the efficient, powerful blade. While the most common
>   crystals used in the process were from the Adega system, Ilum, and
>   Dantooine (in the so-called "Crystal Cave"), Jedi and Sith used a
>   variety of crystals to produce various colors, effects and unique
>   abilities. Some crystals could even enhance the Force skills of a
>   particular user. Other gems, such as colored crystals or diamonds,
>   were used exclusively for prismatic effects.
>
> Metal was usually chosen to make up the hilt, but a casing carved from
>   the Brylark tree, wood that is strong as metal, would also work.
>
> The weapon drew power from an appropriately-sized [Diatium power cell](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/what-powers-a-lightsaber).

Here You can read [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_Test_of_Strength) how the ritual of constructing a new lightsaber works.

So to answer your question : No, there aren't a fixed number of lightsabers in the galaxy.

Here is an extract from the summary of the episode in the link:

> Ancient Jedi tradition! Six younglings are sent to the secret caverns
>   of Ilum, where they are tested by The Gathering, an ancient Jedi
>   ritual where each youngling must harvest a crystal around which they
>   will construct their own lightsaber.

I hope this answers another part of the question as well: **The Jedi gets his lightsaber on successful completion of The Gathering ritual**.

[Here is a link](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/what-powers-a-lightsaber) having the schematic of a lightsaber and stating what powers it.

For more information check [this link](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber).

Luke Skywalker meditated on his crystal in Ben Kenobi's home for many days with only R2-D2 to keep him company.

[image: Luke Skywalker constructs his lightsaber]

These are my suggestions for your doubts.

Hope this helps.